# docker-compose docker containers connection refused

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a container running a service on port 5001, and I am trying to access that service from another container. Whenever I try this I get a connection refused error. I have my docker-compose.yaml file configured like below.

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  server:
    build: 
      context: ./server
    ports:
      - 5001:5001
    networks:
      - local
  client:
    build: 
      context: ./client/wanderingreader
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - server
    networks:
      - local
networks:
  local:
    driver: bridge
```

I am able to ping the server from the client using ping server, but nmap shows all ports are closed.

```bash
/wanderingreader # nmap server
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-06-26 17:54 UTC
Nmap scan report for server (172.22.0.2)
Host is up (0.0000060s latency).
rDNS record for 172.22.0.2: wanderingreader-server-1.wanderingreader_local
All 1000 scanned ports on server (172.22.0.2) are in ignored states.
Not shown: 1000 closed tcp ports (reset)
MAC Address: 02:42:AC:16:00:02 (Unknown)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.32 seconds
```

This is the output of a `docker ps`

```bash
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                              NAMES
3b0c46283abb   wanderingreader_client   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 minutes ago   Up 5 minutes   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, 5001/tcp   wanderingreader-client-1
8d96da5e2629   wanderingreader_server   "/bin/sh -c 'python …"   5 minutes ago   Up 5 minutes   0.0.0.0:5001->5001/tcp             wanderingreader-server-1
```

I have tried other solutions, but I can't seem to get it to work properly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you trying to connect to the container?  What code is running inside the container?  If you have the server incorrectly set to listen on 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0, it won't be reachable from outside its container, with more or less these symptoms; or if your client code is incorrectly using `localhost` as a hostname, you can also get connection errors.  If you can [edit] the question to include a [mcve] that could help highlight what's going wrong.

Comment: @DavidMaze 
While trying to create an example, I ended up figuring it out. I was running a flask server as a module, and for some reason that changed what IP the server was listening on.